# Windows Server 2003 not automatically assigning drive letter to external drives

Tags: windows, usb, drive

My newly rebuilt Windows Server 2003 doesn't automatically assign drive letters to external usb devices.

I have to manually open the Disk Management Console and assign it a drive letter every time.
It does this with two different drives in all USB ports.

I have been doing some reading and I don't have any network drives, I have also already tried USBDLM and it doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Specs: ProLiant ML150 G5 with Windows 2003 Enterprise and all updates installed.

Any ideas on what I can try to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: You could have a look at http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html which might shed some light, or perhaps http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx to show EXACTLY what the puter is doing when you insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open command prompt:

```
C:\>diskpart
diskpart>automount          -tell us if automount is enabled
diskpart>automount enable   -enable automatic drive letter assignment if it is not on
diskpart>automount scrub    -remove old automatic drive letter assignments
diskpart>exit
C:\>exit
```

reboot windows :)

Comment: Thanks Garret, I will try it sometime this week and let you know how it goes.